# Svg clip-path doesn't work in Firefox, IE and Opera

Tags: html, css, svg

I have followed these instructions to make a clipping shape
http://www.guestandguest.com/blog/posts/crop-your-images-in-css-instead-of-using-svg

Here's my code

CSS

```
div#offer {
overflow:hidden;  
width:2028px;  
height:985px;  
margin-top:-765px;  
position:relative;  
/*Chrome,Safari*/  
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(2028px 830px,0px 985px,0px 0px,2028px 0px);  
-ms-clip-path: polygon(2028px 830px,0px 985px,0px 0px,2028px 0px);  
/*Firefox*/  
clip-path: polygon(2028px 830px,0px 985px,0px 0px,2028px 0px);  
clip-path: url('#clipoffer');  

/* iOS support inline encoded svg file*/  
-webkit-mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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) no-repeat;  }
```

and HTML

```
 <div id="offer">
            <svg width="0" height="0">
              <clipPath id="clipoffer">
                <polygon points="2028px 830px,0px 985px,0px 0px,2028px 0px">
                </polygon>
              </clipPath>
            </svg>

            <div class="bg">

            </div>

        </div> <!-- end of div id="offer" -->
```

According to instructions I've followed it should work perfect, but it doesn't. The effect is visible here http://samandera.com/. It works well with Chrome, so you have also proper preview.

Thanks for all kind of help.

Answer (score 3):

The points attribute values must be numbers only. Having px as you have is illegal. The example you quote doesn't have them.

Don't you see errors to this effect in the UA's error log?

```
/*Firefox*/
clip-path: polygon(2028 830,0 985,0 0,2028 0);
-moz-clip-path: url('#clipoffer');
```

There's no such thing as -moz-clip-path. For non webkit you want

```
clip-path: url('http://samandera.com/#clipoffer');
```

Comment: I changed it the way you wrote, but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Well, thanks for help, you were great. :D  I've tried your new solution but it still didn't work. Anyway, I've found completely different way to achieve effect that I need. :)